# How to remove children element from XML in java?

Tags: java, dom, jdom, jdom-2

I want to remove child element from xml.
 My XML file is

```
    <mcss>
        <quest ans="0"> 
            <question><![CDATA[ This is question one]]></question>
            <options>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option one]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option second]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option three]]></option>
            </options>
            <explaination><![CDATA[explaination one]]></explaination>
        </quest>

        <quest ans="0"> 
            <question><![CDATA[ This is question two]]></question>
            <options>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option one]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option second]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option three]]></option>
            </options>
            <explaination><![CDATA[explaination two]]></explaination>
        </quest>
</mcss>
```

if I want to remove question first the how can i do?
output XML..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <mcss>
        <quest ans="0"> 
            <question><![CDATA[ This is question two]]></question>
            <options>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option one]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option second]]></option>
                <option><![CDATA[B<Option three]]></option>
            </options>
            <explaination><![CDATA[explaination two]]></explaination>
        </quest>
</mcss>
```

My java Code to remove question one.

```
    String path="D://test//N2074_set2.xml";
            File structureXml = new File(path);
            SAXBuilder saxb = new SAXBuilder();
            Document document = saxb.build(structureXml);
            Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

            for (int i = 0; i < qestList.size(); i++) {
            Element quesList = (Element) qestList.get(2);
            if(quesList.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("quest"))
                rootElement.removeContent(2);

        }
FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream(path);

            xmlOutput.output(document, file);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to remove child element from xml?

Answer (score 1):

this code delete question first. and it works.

```
 Document document = saxb.build(structureXml);
                Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
                XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                List qestList = rootElement.getChildren();
                Element quesList = (Element) qestList.get(0);
                if(quesList.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("quest")){
                    rootElement.removeContent(quesList);
                }
                FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(path);
                xmlOutput.output(document, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through each `question` node and match for your desire question to be removed, if it is match then You can remove it's parent node.

Comment: I have question number,so dont want to match the qhole question.

Comment: I am not saving in xml bt I have that question no by using this I want to delete question..I hv already delete the question bt my code delete only 1st question not random..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed an easy solution to the problem. If you have any JDOM Content (Element, Attributed, Text, etc.), you can remove it from its parent using the `detach()` method. In your case though, you may want to use an Iterator to go through the Child Elements of the root node, and then remove the matching content from the Iterator.... :

```
for (Iterator<Element> questit = rootElement.getChildren("quest").iterator();
         questit.hasNext();) {
    if (" This is question one".equals(questit.next().getChildText("question")) {
         questit.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot use detach() inside an iterator because that will cause a ConcurrentModificationException.